# Webpack 3 locates .mp4 file but video is not playable

Tags: webpack, loader, animate-cc, .mov

## Webpack 3 locates `.mp4` file but video is not playable

[Clone this project on GitHub](https://github.com/internationalhouseofdonald/go-max)

I've created an animation in Adobe's new Animate CC and exported it as an `.mp4` file

In my webpack.config.js file, I stated that the `file-loader` should be used to load my `.mp4` file like so:

> webpack.config.js

```
  {
    test: /\.(mov|mp4)$/,
    use: [
      'file-loader'
    ]
  }
```

(You can find my `webpack.config.js` source code below)

So why, when I run `webpack` (or rather locally, `webpack` as an `npm` script)

> package.json

```
"build:dev": "webpack --watch",
```

does the browser locate the `.mp4` file

> #### index.html

```
<video loop autoplay controls>
  <source id="arrows" src="c31...random_hash...1611.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

but not play it?

### Other things I've tried

- setting the `video` tag's `src` attribute in JavaScript
- placing the video file next to the index.html in the same directory
- Using a different format (`.mov`)

Here is my source code:

> #### webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/js/main.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-maps',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    port: 3033
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          'html-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$|\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            fallback: "style-loader",
            use: ["css-loader", "sass-loader"]
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          'file-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
        use: [
          'file-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mov|mp4)$/,
        use: [
          'file-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mov|mp4)$/,
        use: [
            'url-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/html/index.html',
      favicon: 'src/images/icon.png'
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css'),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery"
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
        alias: {
            jQuery: "src/js/jquery",
            $: "src/js/jquery"
        }
    }
}
```

> #### main.js

```
import mov from '../media/arrows.mp4';

function render_arrows() {
  var vidtag;
  vidtag = document.getElementById('arrows');
  vidtag.src = mov;
}

render_arrows();
```

As I mentioned earlier, you could also [clone this project on GitHub.](https://github.com/internationalhouseofdonald/go-max)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Specify output file name in webpack.config.js

1. View the [Wepback Documentation: `file-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/)
2. Here is what your loader should look like:

   ```
   {
     test: /\.(mov|mp4)$/,
     use: [
       {
         loader: 'file-loader',
         options: {
           name: '[name].[ext]'
         }  
       }
     ]
   }
   ```

   ### ***Important!***

   You must also import your videos into your `main.js` file like so:

   > #### main.js

   `import video_2 from '../media/video_1.mp4';`
   `import video_1 from '../media/video_2.mov';`
3. Now, in index.html (inside your `src/` directory), you can set the `src` attribute of your `video` tag to a relative path that would point to your video when it loads into the `dist/` directory.
   *Your path should look something like this:*

   ```
       <video loop autoplay controls>
         <source src="./video_1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
       </video>
   ```
4. *Now* run `npm run build` or `npm run build:dev`

### You *can* optionally specify a path like so:

> webpack.config.js

```
    {
      test: /\.(mov|mp4)$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: '[path][name].[ext]'
          }  
        }
      ]
    }
```

---

> ## *Update*

You can also use a **CDN** to deliver your video. Simply set the `src` of your `video` element to a URL.

**ie.**

`src="https://cloudflare.com/?user=574983038&video=cat.mp4"`

If you don't want to pay for a CDN, you can always just use a remote server. I realize that also costs money, but chances are, you probably already have one. Just make sure you have CORS set to deliver to your website:

#### Example using PHP

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST");
```

Since NodeJS has become very popular, this is probably the best method of delivery anyways. As of today (5/11/19), if you try to load your video from a relative path inside your component from a NodeJS server whilst making a GET request to any path other the root directory, it won't be able to find your file. For example, if you have a video located at `https://example.com/videos/593020`, and someone makes a GET request to that URL, your video won't load because NodeJS won't know where to find it.

I could be wrong. You might be able to load it by importing it somewhere else. What I do know is that Node attempts to get your video from whatever path you specify using the path of `window.location.href`. Using a CDN is **much** easier.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! You saved my day! ;)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know the paths needed to be imported in the main.js file.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who is using html-loader like OP, you can configure it to import the videos automatically like this:

```
        {

            test: /\.(html)$/,
            use: {
                loader: "html-loader",
                options: {
                    attributes: {
                        list: [
                            {
                                tag: 'img',
                                attribute: 'src',
                                type: 'src',
                            },
                            {
                                tag: 'img',
                                attribute: 'srcset',
                                type: 'srcset',
                            },
                            {
                                tag: 'img',
                                attribute: 'data-src',
                                type: 'src',
                            },
                            {
                                tag: 'img',
                                attribute: 'data-srcset',
                                type: 'srcset',
                            },
                            {
                                tag: 'video',
                                attribute: 'src',
                                type: 'src',
                            },
                            {
                                tag: 'source',
                                attribute: 'src',
                                type: 'src',
                            },
                            {
                                tag: 'source',
                                attribute: 'srcset',
                                type: 'srcset',
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

See more info on [html-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/html-loader/)